# How to force a requery of a Query that populates a ComboBox?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a ComboBox (cboTipoVoz) which is populated by a query (qryTipoDeVoz). This query is based on a table (it retrieves some records from the table). At a certain point, I add a record to the table and I add to the query a condition that reflects that new record [in a subroutine, UpdateQuery (see below)].

Then, I do the requery of the combo box, but it does not show the new added record, although it is already in the table and it is written in the query from where the combo is populated.
How can I force the ComboBox to show the new added record in the drop list?

“Main code”:

```
            ' NewVoice has just been added to the table
    
            ' Updates the Query
            Call UpdateQuery(NewVoice)
'
            ' Check whether the query has been updated with "NewVoice"
            Dim rst As Recordset
            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryTipoDeVoz")
            With rst
                .MoveLast
                .MoveFirst
                Do While Not .EOF
                    Debug.Print .Fields(0), .Fields(1)
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
                .Close
            End With
            Set rst = Nothing
            
            Me.cboTipoVoz.Undo
    
            Me.cboTipoVoz.Requery
                       
            ' Now, I can't see the "NewVoice" in the drop list. What is wrong here?
```

And the UpdateQuery sub:

```
Public Sub UpdateQuery(strVoice As String)

Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strLeft As String
Dim strRight As String
Dim ipos As Integer
Dim strAdd As String
'
'
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryTipoDeVoz")
strSQL = qdf.SQL
'
ipos = InStr(strSQL, ";")
strSQL = Left(strSQL, ipos)
'
ipos = InStr(strSQL, "ORDER") - 5
strLeft = Left(strSQL, ipos)
strRight = Right(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - ipos)
'
strAdd = " Or (tblTipoIntervencao.TipoDeIntervencao)='" & strVoice & "'"
'
qdf.SQL = strLeft & strAdd & strRight
'
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to add a new record to lookup table 'on-the-fly' during data entry, use combobox NotInList event. What is the combobox RowSource SQL? Why apply filter to combobox data?

Comment: Perhaps you miss to _close_ the query with the revised SQL: `qdf.Close`.

Comment: Could you try :  Me.cboTipoVoz.recordsource = "" followed by Me.cboTipoVoz.recordsource = "Select * from qryTipoDeVoz"

Comment: Thank you all. All suggestions helped me to solve the problem, especially that from Mathias Z. However, I only managed to do it with combo.rowsource , not with combo.recordsource.